# How can I know that graceful shutdown is completed in IIS?

Tags: shutdown, iis

As Microsoft [says](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/app-offline?view=aspnetcore-6.0) we can place a `app_offline.htm` in the root of a website, and it gracefully shuts down the site.

However, I want to know when the graceful shutdown process is completed in bat files.

I used `appcmd list site "siteName"` to see the status, and the status won't change.

So I'm stuck at knowing this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your application can know when the shutdown is finished, using the
[Application_End function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms178473(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN):

> Called once per lifetime of the application before the application is unloaded.

It's up to your application to wait for all threads to terminate
before finishing its own shutdown.
When the `Application_End` function exists, all remaining threads are
killed and the app terminates.

During your wait in Application_End for your threads to exit from
the wait state, the site is not longer accepting web connections and
will not respond to requests, so your threads should exit as soon as
possible.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my need. I need to know about graceful shutdown, *inside command line*, not inside my ASP.NET Application.

Comment: The application should then signal its termination by some means, perhaps via some text file. All applications execute inside the IIS executable, and there is no way of knowing what exactly it is doing now or did before. Only the application knows.

Comment: OK, now I understood. You mean I should use some sort of inter-process communication for this purpose. Or some signal somewhere to know it has happened. It might work. But it's a dirty solution.

Comment: Rule for a successful programmer : nothing that works is dirty. You could fancy it up by using a semaphore or other advanced inter-process mechanism.